# What happened to the Jedi trainees that Kylo took?

Tags: star-wars, the-last-jedi

In *The Last Jedi*:

> Luke says that when Ben Solo fell to the dark side, he took a number
>  of student Jedi trainees from Luke's temple. Kylo Ren then killed the
>  rest.

**So what happened to these other trainee Jedi?** Were they killed by Snoke or Ren? Where did they go?

Comment: Good question, as far as I can tell, we don't know

Comment: @Edlothaid Maybe there will be a new answer with any upcoming canon?

Comment: From the movie we don't really know what happened at that time. Luke and Kylo have each given different explanations of what happened, so it is possible that it will turn out that part of Luke's account wasn't entirely accurate. Though at this time I cannot imagine why Luke would have told that part if it wasn't true.

Comment: @kasperd it appeared to me that both explanations were accurate _from a certain point of view_.

Comment: We will find out in Ep9 when snoke leads the Knights of Ren against the grey jedi created by kilo and Rey....  Oh wait it's Disney

Comment: I assumed at the time that they were, or would become, the Knights of Ren. But I don't think there's enough existing information to prove or disprove that.

Comment: I figured they became Snoke's praetorian guard, but I don't think this is actually the case.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## We don't know (yet)

What you've stated in your question is all that we know so far. As was mentioned in the film and novelization regarding the [destruction of Luke's Jedi](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Destruction_of_Luke_Skywalker%27s_Jedi), some willingly left with him while the rest were killed. Considering they weren't all killed, we can at the very least surmise that Kylo/Snoke had some Force related use for them. Given that these students would have been training alongside him under Luke, it's not unreasonable to theorize that they would continue to follow him afterwards as the [Knights of Ren](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Knights_of_Ren). But as the knights themselves were not included as part of The Last Jedi, we still have no definitive answer.

It's worth mentioning that [according to director Rian Johnson](http://comicbook.com/2018/01/17/star-wars-the-last-jedi-knight-of-ren-rian-johnson-comments/) regarding the Knights of Ren:

> We have a very full movie already there literally was just not room for another element...

If there was no room for expanding on their story, there certainly wasn't enough to dive into the missing trainees either. Whether there is a link between the two or not we'll have to wait until Episode IX to find out.

Comment: This answer could be improved by including the quote by Johnson in the text.

Comment: @TheDarkLord The only issue I have with including the quote directly is that it's more a footnote acknowledging that the Knights of Ren didn't appear in TLJ. It makes no specific reference to the Jedi trainees or their fate, and doesn't provide anything about the Knights that would affirm or deny a connection.

Comment: It seems to me to be a firm piece of evidence for why we don't know what happened to them at this stage. I.e. We would do if Johnson had found a place for them in the film, but he didn't.

Comment: @TheDarkLord I think I might see what you're getting at. Tangentially, if Johnson couldn't find a place to include the knights, stands to reason that the trainees likewise would have been too much to include, and may come up later (connection to the knights or not). I can find a way to work that in.

Answer (score -1):

Well, although we haven't seen them, it's stated that Kylo formed them into "The Knights of Ren"

This Wikipedia entry includes a picture of the Knights (Taking place during Rey's vision in TFA) as well as an explanation for why they are missing from The Last Jedi (There was no room in the film)

http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Knights_of_Ren

Considering Kylo's rather crudely constructed lightsaber, made with a cracked Kyber crystal, it's possible that he is the only one with a saber in this image due to a lack of resources.

Comment: The wiki is not a good source of information as it's fan-written. Where does it say (originally) that the Knight of Ren were these students?