# Did the students who fled with Kylo Ren become the Knights of Ren?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens, the-last-jedi, knights-of-ren

In The Last Jedi, it is mentioned that some students followed Kylo Ren on the run from the academy. In a document, are you informed of the fate of these students?

[image: The runaways of Ren?]

Comment: Could you clarify your title? I can see it going in multiple directions and am not sure what you are trying to ask.

Comment: The other students, are the Ren Knights?

Comment: This is certainly the prevailing theory right now, but I've yet to see anything confirming it.

Comment: This is a dupe of [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/176918/68872)

Comment: Thanks @Edlothiad. I am new here :D

Comment: @DevAires no worries! You might get more insight looking at the comments there and maybe your next question will take off!

Comment: @DevAires I recognise that your question is different from the [one](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/176918/what-happened-to-the-jedi-trainees-that-kylo-took) I asked, so no I do not think your question is a dupe of mine.

Comment: @Brickgunner The question is "In a document, are you informed of the fate of these students?" that's identical to your question. Duplicates aren't a bad thing. If anything they're a good thing.

Comment: @Edlothaid ok I get where you're going

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<del>**The Knights of Ren were not Force-Sensitive** (at least that is how they are [portrayed](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wTHFrqee3SM)) so</del> it is unlikely (but **plausible and possible**) that these other students joined the Knights of Ren. Another answer that has come to my attention is that these students that left with Ren *could* have became the Red guards seen in Snokes throne room, as suggested by *Star Wars Explained* -

.

EDIT: Some members of The Knights Ren *probably were* force sensitive (with the exception of Kylo Ren), but this has not been shown yet in canon (as of December 2017.)

Comment: The first line of the wookiepedia article you link says that they are force sensitive...

Comment: I also suspected that the Praetorian Guards were The Knights of Ren, but I'm not sure if this is officially the case.

Comment: @JoshB. Apparently Rian Johnson has stated [in a podcast](https://soundcloud.com/empiremagazine/star-wars-the-last-jedi-spoiler-special) that the Praetorian guards are not the Knights of Ren: _"I guess I could’ve used them **in place of** the Praetorian guards but then it would feel like wasting them because all those guards had to die. And if Kylo had some kind of connection to them it would’ve added a complication that wouldn’t have helped the scene… Truth is, I just didn’t see a place for them in the movie."_

Comment: @StevenRands Interesting, thanks for sharing that! I hope we get to see the Knights of Ren in Episode IX.